# JSP de Erro não é exibida - HTTP Status 404 – Não Encontrado

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, java-8

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Código da jsp de exibir mensagens de erro:

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Error Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Opps...</h1>
    <p>Sorry, an error occurred.</p>
    <p>Here is the exception stack trace:</p>

    <select>
        <c:forEach items="${erros}" var="e">
            <option value="${e.getMessage()}"></option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <br/>

    Clicar<a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

> Web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:javaee="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<!-- <display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name> -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/pages/login.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>loginsuccess.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>usuariosList.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>novoUsuario.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/errors.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<!-- <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error-404.jsp</location>
</error-page> -->
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você está tentando fazer... Você forçou um erro na sua aplicação para tentar testar a página de erro `/WEB-INF/pages/errors.jsp`, e em vez disso, deu erro 404? É esse o problema? Se for isso, percebi que no seu XML você configurou a página de erro para `errors.jsp`, mas no seu screenshot está `erros.jsp` (está faltando uma letra **r**). Será que você não se confundiu e criou o arquivo com esse nome errado dentro do projeto?

Comment: Isso ai eu tinha percebido e corrigi, o problema é que não estou conseguindo carregar uma lista de exceções que nessa pagina, após a validação dos atributos do objeto. Ou tela de login. esse é meu problema!

Comment: O problema ainda continua